# Facing issues regarding python starbase fetch function to fetch byte and string data

Tags: python, hbase

I recently came across starbase module for the connectivity of my python script to hbase.

I will give you a brief of what problem exactly I am facing and then will break it down step by step to give you a clear image of it.

I have some data in my hbase table called 'dummy_table'. Earlier the keys in this table were all strings delimited by \x00 padding. Here is an example:-

```
00:00:00:00:00:00\x001441767600\x001\x0040.0.2.1\x00
```

Now I will explain what the fields actually are:-

```
00:00:00:00:00:00 - This is the mac address
1441767600 - This is the time in epoch (Wed Sep  9 03:00:00 UTC 2015)
1 - this is the customer id
40.0.2.1 - this is store id
```

Since they were all strings earlier It was very easy to fetch the values corresponding to such keys.

Here is the code snippet:-

```
from starbase import Connection
import starbase
C = Connection(host='10.10.122.136', port='60010')

get_table = C.table('dummy_table')
mac = "00:00:00:00:00:00"
hours = "1441767600"
cus_id = "1"
store_id = "40.0.2.1"
create_query = '%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00' % (mac,hours,cus_id,store_id)
fetch_result = get_table.fetch(create_query)
print fetch_result
```

Earlier this little piece of code used to give me exact value which is a hash

```
{count:100}
```

Now, the problem is that the time which is 1441767600 is stored in 8 bytes form in hbase for better performance purpose since the amount of data in hbase is pretty huge.

Now the row/key in the hbase looks something like this:-

```
00:00:00:00:00:00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xEF\xA0\xB0\x001\x0040.0.2.1\x00
```

Breaking this down:-

```
00:00:00:00:00:00 - Mac address
\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xEF\xA0\xB0 - time in bytes (1441767600 if converted into long from bytes)
1 - customer id
40.0.2.1 - store_id
```

Now if I run similar code with minimal changes so that python takes the bytes as string, it doesn't work.
Here is the code snippet:-

```
from starbase import Connection
import starbase
C = Connection(host='10.10.122.136', port='60010')

get_table = C.table('dummy_table')
mac = "00:00:00:00:00:00"
hours = "\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00U\\xEF\\xA0\\xB0"
cus_id = "1"
store_id = "40.0.2.1"
create_query = '%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00%s\x00' % (mac,hours,cus_id,store_id)
fetch_result = get_table.fetch(create_query)
print fetch_result
```

When I run this, it gives me "None" as the result.

Funny thing is when I directly access my hbase and run the get query for the same, it works.
Here is the hbase get query for the same:-

```
get 'dummy_table', "00:00:00:00:00:00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00U\xEF\xA0\xB0\x001\x0040.0.2.1\x00", COLUMN => ['cf1:count:toLong']
```

This gives the output as:-

```
100
```

which is correct.
I have searched quite alot but I haven't come across anything that would solve my problem.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of struggle I found out another python module named happybase which connects python to hbase to fetch/insert data.

Happybase seems to work properly in this case. https://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-the-happybase-package

Starbase scanning functions are currently under development. Thats what it says on their website. http://starbase.readthedocs.org/en/0.1/